# ImportError: libXrender.so.1 on OpenShift Online Plaform

Tags: python, docker, openshift, opencv

I was building a web app on OpenShift Online Platform with streamlit, PyTorch and OpenCV. It had been ran well until it started executing the Python Script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 11, in <module>
  import cv2
File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I know the solution to it is simply installing the missing library "libXrender". But the thing is that I can not find a way to implement it (I tried docker already). So is possible to turn on a terminal console on OpenShift Online Platform?

PS:
I am using starter package of OpenShift and the following is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch:1.4-cuda10.1-cudnn7-runtime
RUN pip install virtualenv
# only needed when using OpenShift
RUN apt-get install libxrender1
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/venv
RUN virtualenv venv -p python3
ENV PATH="VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

# Install dependencies
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get install -y libglib2.0-0 libsm6 libxrender1 libxext6
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copying all files over
COPY . /app

# Expose port 
ENV PORT 8501

# cmd to launch app when container is run
CMD streamlit run app.py

# streamlit-specific commands for config
ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
RUN mkdir -p /root/.streamlit
RUN bash -c 'echo -e "\
[general]\n\
email = \"\"\n\
" > /root/.streamlit/credentials.toml'

RUN bash -c 'echo -e "\
[server]\n\
enableCORS = false\n\
" > /root/.streamlit/config.toml'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what's in your `requirements.txt`, I believe you can migitate this issue by installing the headless version (server environment) of `opencv-python` which is `opencv-python-headless`. Then you can most likely remove also `libsm6 libxrender1 libxext6`. These are dependencies which are used to display GUI windows which are not usually needed in server (headless) environments.